# opennebula how to list HOST column with its last octet

Tags: opennebula

Does anyone know why when running

```
onevm list
```

OR

```
onevm list --list HOST
```

The last octet is hidden ? I can only see xxx.xxx.xxx.???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command uses a fixed width for the host column. You can customize the visible columns and their width in the /etc/one/cli/ [yaml files](http://docs.opennebula.org/4.6/user/references/cli.html).

Comment: YOU ARE A KING !